# NodeJS, use Eclipse Debugger for variables inspection?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, node.js, v8

I'm following https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger 
and leaves me with questions

1. How can I see what variables contain?
2. How can I execute arbitrary commands?

This is similar to webkit's inspector. You can do both there, it has a console tab to execute whatever you want and inputing variable's name will display its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built my own tool for the time being. 
https://github.com/ketamynx/node-codein